# roots of equation $ e^{2x}\sin (2x) +7=0$

Tags: calculus, arithmetic

Let a,b,c be roots of equation $ e^{2x}\sin2x -7=0$ then roots of equation $ e^{2x}\sin2x +7=0$ lies between p and q where

1. Both p and q $\in$(a, b)
2. Both p and q $\in$(b, c)
3. p $\in $(a, b) and q $\in$(b, c)
4. p $\in $(a, b) and q $\notin$(b, c)

my attempt:
I plotted graphs of $\sin2x$, $ e^{-2x}$, $-e^{-2x}$. But I have doubt further from here

Comment: Plot the graphs $y=\sin 2x$ and $y=-7e^{-2x}$.

Comment: What I don't understand in this question is following: From [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+e%5Ex+sin%28x%29+-7+for+x%3D9+to+100) you can see that $e^{2x}\sin 2x-7$ has infinitely many zeroes. The question is phrased as if it only had three.

Answer (score 1):

Given the location of the roots (and assuming they are consecutive and $a<b<c$), you have
$f(x)>0$ in $(a,b)$ and $f(x)<0$ in $(b,c)$, or conversely.

Now you are looking for the solutions of $f(x)=14$, which are both in $(a,b)$ or both in $(b,c)$ (you cannot tell).